# zsh up-line-or-history does not work in gnome-terminal and tmux

Tags: 13.04, gnome-terminal, zsh, tmux

I use Ubuntu 13.04, zsh with oh-my-zsh and `up-line-or-history` is bind to up arrow (default settings of oh-my-zsh). But this work only in urxvt.

I try to use `DEBIAN_PREVENT_KEYBOARD_CHANGES` in my zshrc, but this does not help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same problem, solved with:

```
export TERM=rxvt-unicode
```

then checking:

```
echo $TERM
```

ZSH history works and rxvt-unicode supports colors, while rxvt does not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking for an answer.

Here is what worked for me in Ubuntu 13.10 and TMUX.
Updated `~/.zshenv` (not `~/.zshrc`) with

```
DEBIAN_PREVENT_KEYBOARD_CHANGES=yes
```